# Javascript remove disabled attribute using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find an input with a class of blocked and remove the disabled attribute.  This is what I have...

```
<input id="test" class="blocked" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Some Value">
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("blocked").removeAttribute("disabled");
</script>
```

This needs to be done using Javascript and not jQuery, why is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write it like below,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blocked")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Since `getElementsByClassName()` will return a node list, Technically a `[object HTMLCollection]`. So You have to access the first element from that collection and invoke the functions that you want.

Comment: Makes sense now, it returns an array as there could be more than one class found.  Thank you for clarifying

Comment: @fightstarr20 Its not an array, It is an array like object. So you cannot treat them as an array.